# Why don't elves have more babies?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, elves

Is there a particular reason the elves die off so fast? After the first war against Sauron, I recall the elves being decimated, to the point that they're almost useless army-wise in the trilogy. But I'm guessing men suffered equal or greater losses as well.

Anyways, other races just seem much more capable of repopulating, while is seems like there are incredibly few (if any?) elven children. Considering the fact that elves are immortal, wouldn't their population be the fastest to grow? Also the seem to be perpetually 40 years old, so aren't they eternally fertile as well? Why don't they have more kids and build bigger societies?

Comment: Sex is just so... inelegant...

Comment: @Nerrolken I must disagree

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36104/why-arent-there-any-recognizable-elf-children-in-middle-earth

Comment: @randal'thor That question seems more associated with aging... I'm just wondering why their population kept dwindling when they had every opportunity to flourish.

Comment: With all the answers about repopulating via reproductive activities - and why/why not for elves - how much of their decline also has to do with them getting on boats and going... away? instead of just plain lack of libido?

Comment: They must pay taxes making more then half of their income and can't afford children.

Comment: @Nerrolken In the words of Lords of the Rhymes' song *Back That Elf Up*: "My fly Elf girl's got pointy little ears, been bangin' Elf bottom for five thousand years!"

Comment: I don't think this is any of our business! I've never heard an Elf ask such a personal question about Humans and I think we should take a leaf out of their book and remember our manners!

Comment: We've already seen what happens when beautiful people with super-human abilities get together. They call it the Olympic Village, and there's mating aplenty.

Comment: @WernerCD To be fair though elves have been born in Valinor and the more that go the larger the available partners. So I'm not sure that's really relevant.

Comment: @CJDennis Love the punning there! If you don't catch it I refer to 'Leaf out of their book': Legolas's was called Legolas Greenleaf and it it is the friendship of Gimli and Legolas that the Elves have as much information about the Dwarves as they do. Iirc most information known about dwarves in general is because of this friendship. Not that I think it's an inappropriate question though I somehow think that maybe you weren't serious too. I personally think it's an interesting question and so did Tolkien: hence the essays in Morgoth's Ring.

Comment: @WernerCD Because that's not the way it is. They did lose interest. Has nothing to do with them going to Valinor. Remember also that not all of them returned to Middle-earth. Also: **there were Elves that were born in Valinor** which is another reason it has nothing to do with why they have no children as the ages went by.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Tolkien himself addresses this in an essay called "Laws and Customs Among the Eldar". There are essentially two problems:

1. **Elvish libido diminishes over time.** Contrary to popular belief (and outward appearance, from a human perspective), Elves *do* age; and as they get older, they get less interested in procreation.
2. **Having children is *exhausting*.** The Elves believe that their child-bearing process draws a heavier physical and spiritual toll on them, compared to what it does to humans. They're understandable reluctant to have a lot of kids, because what's the point in having a dozen kids if doing so might *literally* kill you?

From "Laws and Customs":

> It might be thought that, since the Eldar do not (as Men deem) grow old in body, they may bring forth children at any time in the ages of their lives. But this is not so. For the Eldar do indeed grow older, even if slowly: the limit of their lives is the life of Arda, which though long beyond the reckoning of Men is not endless, and ages also. Moreover their body and spirit are not separated but coherent. As the weight of the years, with all their changes of desire and thought, gathers upon the spirit of the Eldar, so do the impulses and moods of their bodies change. *[...]*
>
> Also the Eldar say that in the begetting [conceiving], and still more in the bearing of children, greater share and strength of their being, in mind and in body, goes forth than in the making of mortal children. For these reasons it came to pass that the Eldar brought forth few children; and also that their time of generation was in their youth or earlier life, unless strange and hard fates befell them.
>
> <sup><sub>*History of Middle-earth* X *Morgoth's Ring* Part 3: "The Later *Quenta Silmarillion*" Chapter 2: "The Second Phase" *Laws and Customs Among the Eldar*</sub></sup>

That last point about the toll on their mind and body is worth expanding on, and fortunately Tolkien does this later in the essay:

> [A]ll the Eldar, being aware of it in themselves, spoke of the passing of much strength, both of mind and of body, into their children, in bearing and begetting. Therefore they hold that the *fëa* [soul], though unbegotten, draws nourishment directly from the *fëa* of the mother while she bears and nourishes the *hrondo* [body; later changed to the word *hroä*], and mediately but equally from the father, whose *fëa* is bound in union with the mother's and supports it.
>
> <sup><sub>*History of Middle-earth* X *Morgoth's Ring* Part 3: "The Later *Quenta Silmarillion*" Chapter 2: "The Second Phase" *Laws and Customs Among the Eldar*</sub></sup>

Comment: Little runts, draining your bank account AND your life force!

Comment: @Nerrolken They do drain your life force, but at the same time you're happier than you ever knew you could be. While you're convinced your kids will be the end of you, at the same time you know you wouldn't hesitate to lay down your life in order to preserve theirs.

Comment: @ShemSeger: Apparently the Elves disagree.

Comment: Good answer, it should be noted that the elves are like mini Valar in may ways. Great acts of creation drain them in the same way that it drained the Valar (who couldn't recreate things like the 2 trees after they were destroyed because the original creation had sapped them), including creating other immortals.

Comment: Great answer, but note that "conceiving" as a parenthetical explanation of "begetting"  makes no sense. Begetting (making someone get) is what men do, conceiving (receiving) is what women do. So "in the begetting, and still more in the bearing of children" covers both sexes. This is also taken up later with the phrase "bearing and begetting", which doesn't mean that one person does both but is again meant to cover both sexes.

Comment: @HansAdler It may not be strictly etymologically correct, but that's how Tolkien uses the word (with a certain amount of simplification for the non-linguists following along); later he discusses how typically a year passes between begetting and bearing, and that Elves celebrate their "Begetting Day" rather than the date of their birth. I'm not enough of a linguist to comment on the choice, just trying to make sure as many people understand as possible

Comment: @JasonBaker `Elves celebrate their "Begetting Day"`.  I can imagine how that might go... "Son, this is the day that your mother and I..."  "Dad, stop! Ewwwwwww!"

Comment: @Jason Baker: Then it appears that Tolkien uses *bearing* like German *gebären* in the sense of giving birth, whereas perhaps a more usual meaning in English is being pregnant - a state that lasts 9 months in humans and maybe a year in elves. But my point was that a woman *conceives* a child at the exact moment when, or at most a day after (depending on the precise definitions used), her partner *begets* the child. Following the old theory of the man passing over a kind of embryo, it's the same relation as *giving* and *taking*, so they are clearly not synonyms.

Comment: @JasonBaker - +1.  Like it or not, you are quickly becoming the new Darth Melkor.

Comment: @ShemSeger Maybe for some people. Definitely not me. I couldn't think of many worse things than having a child. Personal preference but children absolutely do not make everyone happy; and people have told me that it's different when it's your own. I tell them they didn't really dislike kids then. Yes a good parent would be everything for their children but not everyone is happy about having kids - some too late (and shame on them) but others know better (and good on them).

Comment: “Their time of generation was in their youth _or earlier life_” — So the elves have kids before they’re even young, i.e., when they’re kids themselves? I smell an international diplomatic scandal…

Comment: FWIW, if you toss in the point of Feanor being such a burden to give birth to that his mom (roughly) expire,s your excellent answer might be excellenter.  

Answer (score 16):

## Elves only have a small number of children in a small amount of time.

Elves only procreate for a certain period of their lives, as Tolkien said (in quotes):

> The bad news is that elves tend to lose interest in sex after they've had kids. "With the exercise of the power (of generation), the desire soon ceases, and the mind turns to other things…they have many other urges of body and of mind which their nature urges them to fulfil." They do look back happily on the sexually-active time in their lives, though, a period of one to several hundred years.
>
> <sub>[What Tolkien Officially Said About Elf Sex](http://www.ansereg.com/what_tolkien_officially_said_abo.htm); quote inside from "Laws and Customs of the Eldar", one of Tolkien's essays.</sub>

When they *do* have children, there aren't many:

> Seven children was the usual upper limit in ancient times, but in future ages, partly due to varying levels of corruption in various elven societies, these norms were often exceeded rarely, even when corrupted do they ever succumb to deeds of Lust.
>
> <sub>[Elf children](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Elf_children)</sub>

So it's once and done, while Elves are young, and then things slow down. For most of their lives, Elves do not have young (even relatively young) children.

Comment: Can someone translate that second quote into modern English?  I can't quite parse it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston In the past it was usual that no more than seven children were had. Later on due to varying degrees of corruption in various elven societies the norms were often exceed but rarely. And therein lies the problem: often and rarely conflict with each other. This makes one question if the rest of it is relevant; I would say not. Not that I think seven children isn't many...

Comment: @Pryftan, looking at the linked source (via the Wayback Machine) it isn't clear to me whether this is a direct quote from Tolkien or not.  If it is, I'm thinking perhaps it got mangled somehow.

Comment: @HarryJohnston After I wrote that I thought I should have added that it doesn’t seem like Tolkien wrote it himself although he certainly had some archaic writings. He even wrote about this in at least one letter. I did also think of another way it could be interpreted, the contradiction, but not really: it’s as you say if his it’s mangled. Which btw I also meant to say I love that you used the word *parse* for that’s the word I use for that type of thing. Programmer’s thinking. Mangled is also a good word but so is corruption e.g. memory corruption!

Comment: @HarryJohnston I just posted an answer on the subject of numbers and indeed the quote seems not only incorrect but not even - as we both thought - Tolkien's writing.

Comment: *A small amount of time* is a very strange way to refer to *a period of one to several hundred years*.  Human child-bearing window is about twenty-five years, and we have no problem making more of ourselves.  I really don't think the amount of time is a problem here.

Comment: @MishaR For humans yes. For the Elves several hundred years is rather a small amount of time.

Comment: @Pryftan, I believe [parse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parse) (see meaning 1) is the correct word in the context of linguistics too, and presumably predates the use in computing.  On the other hand, I've been programming since the late 70s, so yeah, maybe so. :-)  I like "commentator" too.  Speaking of programming makes me think how much that sentence looks like something Google Translate might have come up with - perhaps it originated as something in another language?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes well that would make sense wouldn't it? Language and all. I'm not that old but I've been programming in some forms or another since say the early 1990s. But even so I would say that even if the word is *parse* what comes to mind is certainly in part because of the fact you're a programmer. And you know I really haven't a clue how that sentence originated; I guess it could be but if it was from an English wiki site would it be that way? Either way it makes little sense if any. Let's just call it **undefined behaviour** and be done with it...? Something like that :)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Oh and thanks for the comment on commentators (though that's from my own answer). But the changing sort of reminds me of the American publishers changing things in The Lord of the Rings; things like: *further* to *farther*; *try and* to *try to*; *elven* to *elfin* and so on. Things in other words that annoyed Tolkien (and rightfully so). I'm inclined to call it presumptuous at best but really worse than that; however with all the things going on in my life atm I won't go there - but it still really annoyed me.

Comment: @Pryftan That doesn't matter here. If the question is *why don't Elves have more babies*, the only thing that matters is their child-bearing ability and the absolute amount of child-bearing time. Whether not it's a lot compared to the rest of their life is irrelevant.

Comment: @MishaR Clearly. I was saying though that for Elves *A small amount of time* **is not all that odd of a way to think about** *several hundred years*. It matters. But only in response to your comment does it matter.

Comment: @Pryftan Seeing as it had nothing to do with what I was referring to, it actually isn't relevant to anything. It seems pedantic, and nothing more.

Comment: @MishaR Maybe you're just saying that for us humans it seems odd but you also realise that for Elves it doesn't? In which case fine. If not also fine. Pedantic? Perhaps. Either way I am a literal thinker and my reply is valid in that case. But yes let's drop it. :)

Comment: I just want to say about this: *Seven children was the usual upper limit in ancient times, but in future ages, partly due to varying levels of corruption in various elven societies, these norms were often exceeded rarely* That is 100% false. A perfect example of Wikis being a source that you have to be careful with. As I quoted in my answer there were seldom more than *four* and the number grew less as the ages went on. And there was not a single Elf who had more than 7. *Deeds of lust*? I’m wondering where they get that idea. Anyway that quote is just wrong in every way.

Comment: Also as for the first quote it would be improved if you could separate the quote from the other part of it. I am also not certain with they look back at their sexual times. I find that a strange statement to make. For them time is both slow and fast at once but it's also very painful. The Three Rings were to preserve and Sauron was able to deceive them (some of them) by manipulating them into the wonder of Valinor - which is where their heart is. I don't see it as bad news that they lose interest. That's someone's opinion and has nothing to do with the actual reasons.

Answer (score 7):

To supplement Jason Baker's [excellent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/91599/85680) I wanted to add something about the number of children also from the same essay in Morgoth's Ring. I would like to point out that there seems to be something in [HDE's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/91597/85680) that must have been sourced from a wiki; however commentator Harry Johnston in that answer asked if anyone could translate a quote in that answer. I did so but he and I both thought it didn't look like Tolkien. Since it talks about number of children Elves tend to have I thought I would add something from the same essay that Jason cited:

> The Eldar wedded for the most part in their youth and soon after their fiftieth year. They had *few children* but these were very dear to them. Their families, or houses, were held together by love and a deep feeling for kinship in mind and body; and the children needed little governing or teaching. There **were seldom *more than four* children** in any house **and the number grew less as the ages past** but even in the days of old, **while the Eldar were still few and *eager to increase their kind*** Fëanor was **renowned as the father of *seven* sons**, and the histories record none that surpassed him(4).

### Footnotes:

(4): There were actually two drafts of this essay; Christopher shows the main one and then shows divergences. In this essay at footnote four he has this to say about version A:

> '.. while the Eldar were still few, and eager to increase their kind, before the weight of years lay on them, there is no record of any number more than seven', with 'seldom' written later above 'no'.

### Summary

In the earlier ages they were more eager to increase their kind, when they had fewer. As the ages went by this desire decreased - as Jason's answer points out; the other answer suggests that seven was the upper limit but *usually it was no more than **four*** and as the ages went by the number grew less. Fëanor was one of the ones who actually had **seven and *none surpassed him*** in this.

Comment: I've rolled back the changes; the word *is* **commentator** and it is Morgoth's Ring. There was no need to make any changes that I could see and I don't appreciate, actually, changing a word when the word is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 7):

### Elves only have children once in their life, and it saps a lot of strength so they don't do it during war.

In circa 1959, J.R.R. Tolkien wrote a series of texts which he collectively called "Of Time in Arda". These are published in *The Nature of Middle-earth*.

> It may also be noted that **in each Elvish life there was normally only one period of begetting or bearing children, whenever begun;** and that the length of this period was variable, as were the number of children produced. It might occupy from 12 to about 60 years (occasionally more). The children numbered usually 2, 3, or 4. ...
>
> Thus we may observe that all matters of *growth and development*, which belong to the separate nature of the *hröa*, engaged in its own process of achieving its complete and mature form, and which are not under the will or conscious control of the *fëa*, proceed far slower among the Quendi than among Men. Gestation, therefore, proceeds according to the growth and ageing scale of the Quendi, and occupies ¾ *yên*, or 108 MY[= Middle-earth years].
>
> During all this time the parents are aware of the growth of the unborn child, and live in much longer and more deeply-felt joy and expectation; for childbirth is not among the Eldar accompanied by pain. **It is nonetheless not an easy or light matter, for it is achieved by a much greater expense of the vigour of *hröa* and *fëa* (of “youth” as the Eldar say) than is usual among Men; and is followed after the begetting by a time of quiescence and withdrawal.** The Elf-women also are usually quiescent and withdrawn before and after birth. **For these reasons, the Eldar did not (if they could avoid it) enter into the “Time of the Children” in times of trouble, or wandering. There were thus no marriages or births during the Great March; nor again during the journey of the Ñoldor from Aman to Beleriand, and births were few during all the War against Morgoth.** For the same cause, Men who had dealings with the Eldar often saw far less of the Elf-women, and might even be unaware that some Elven-king or lord had a wife. For the withdrawal and quiescence of the wife might occupy the whole time of his sojourn among the Eldar, or indeed much of his whole mortal life-time. For this “withdrawal”, occupying from three to four “months” or twelfths of a “year”, that is one quarter to one third of a *yên*, would in mortal terms endure for about 36 to 48 years.
> <sub>*The Nature of Middle-earth* - "The Quendi compared with Men"</sub>

> In the case of *Elf-women*: marriage and child-bearing took place earlier, their first child being born before they were of age 20. Later indeed some postponement was usual so that marriage at 21 was the most usual time; though any age up to 36 (18 + 18) was not uncommon. **In days of trouble, or of travel and unsettled life, the begetting of children was naturally avoided or postponed; and since the postponement especially of the first child-bearing or begetting prolonged the “youth” or physical vigour of the Quendi,** this might occur up to a female age of about 72 (18 + 54) – but a first child-bearing seldom occurred after this age. ...
>
> At all times, unless circumstances interfered and separation were forced upon spouses by wars or exile, the Quendi desired to dwell in company with husband or wife during the bearing of a child and its early growth. **Also as a rule, they preferred to arrange their lives so as to have a consecutive “Time of the Children” in which all of their children were born – but this of course often, especially in the troubled early years, proved impossible.** After a birth, even if a consecutive *Onnalúmë* or ‘Time of Children’ was achieved, a rest was naturally always taken. This was governed by “growth-time”, and so was usually not less than 12 *löar* (= 1 growth-year); but it might be much more; and usually was increased progressively between each birth for consecutive series: as 12 : 24 : 36 : 48 etc.
> <sub>*The Nature of Middle-earth* - "Natural Youth and Growth of the Quendi"</sub>

A few points may be noted:

- Elves like to arrange all of their childbearing so that it happens in a continuous interval
- Depending on the number of children this interval can be anywhere from 144 to 720 years. (They need progressively larger recovery periods between each child.
- They like to plan their lives so that this one period happens during a time of peace, when both parents can be home

Comment: Luthien would seem to have been past her child-bearing years by the time she met Beren. Likewise Arwen with Aragorn.
Whatever is needed to make the story work, I guess. Plus those were elf-human unions, not elf-elf.

Comment: @FlaStorm32 - The ages Tolkien gives here are in dog, sorry, elf years. One elf year in the third age is equal to 100 human years. Tolkien wasn't very worried about Luthien's timeline because he could always change that if needed, but he does discuss how these rules affect Arwen. "*She was born (according to LR) in TA 241. She was married to Aragorn in TA 3019. She was then 2,778 years old, or in human terms nearly 28. This in elvish terms is a very suitable age. Her wedding was in any case inevitably postponed by the War of the Ring and the preceding troubles.*"

Comment: It is probably worth noting that Tolkien changed his mind on elven aging - "Laws and Customs of the Eldar" in Morgoth's Ring says the usual age for elves to marry is under 100 (apparently mortal/Sun) years.

Comment: @cometaryorbit - The text quoted in this answer (and indeed most of the "Time and Aging" stuff from NoMe) was written *after* Laws and Custom of the Eldar,

Comment: I know. I just thought it was worth mentioning because this was not Tolkien's idea at the time LOTR was written (even Laws and Customs is after that) so it may not be perfectly in harmony with details of stories written before. (And in fact Nature of Middle Earth's "Difficulties in Chronology" shows that Tolkien couldn't make Maeglin work on this time scale, since he had to be adult in less than 400 Sun Years -- so Eldar in Beleriand had to grow more quickly... "Maeglin for example, born in Bel. 120, was in only 200 years (=20) an adult: sc. he was in life-age 20 in Bel. 320. But in 495, when

Comment: Tuor came to Gondolin, he was only (495-320)/100 years older: sc. 175/100 = less than 2 years or about 22." Since Arwen was born in Middle-Earth it's not clear why the same time-scale shouldn't apply to her... I am not sure to what degree these notes can be taken as 'final'.